# Uploading files to Amazon S3 using SigV4 API

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am looking to upload images to amazon S3 using the rest api that they provided. I got to know how to calculate the signing key for `SigV4` from [this](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/sig-v4-authenticating-requests.html) document. 
[This](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/sig-v4-header-based-auth.html) documentation tells you how the request should be signed. But I find it highly confusing as to what should be signed and where should the cannonical request be placed? Should it be placed in a separate header in the request? 
Is there a working example/sample to use `SigV4 rest api` using java?

Answer (score 1):

If you have a very specific reason for not using the provided SDK, the quickest path to getting this working it to look at how the requests are performed in a library where this is already working. You can look at the Java SDK itself to figure this out, but that's a bit dense.

Here is my favorite, although I think it's on sig v3:
http://geek.co.il/2014/05/26/script-day-upload-files-to-amazon-s3-using-bash
You can find out similar examples for v4:
http://geek.co.il/2014/11/19/script-day-amazon-aws-signature-version-4#footnote_0_33255

You can see how everything is compute and what is to be passed in the headers in very few lines of code.

**EDIT**
Look at http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/sig-v4-examples-using-sdks.html#sig-v4-examples-using-sdk-java for exactly what you are looking for. It has the bare minimum to get this going in java.

Answer (score 1):

[aws-v4-signer-java](https://github.com/lucasweb78/aws-v4-signer-java/) is a lightweight, zero-dependency library that makes it easy to generate AWS V4 signatures.

```
String contentSha256 = "e3b0c44298fc1c149afbf4c8996fb92427ae41e4649b934ca495991b7852b855";
HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest("GET", new URI("https://examplebucket.s3.amazonaws.com?max-keys=2&prefix=J"));
String signature = Signer.builder()
        .awsCredentials(new AwsCredentials(ACCESS_KEY, SECRET_KEY))
        .header("Host", "examplebucket.s3.amazonaws.com")
        .header("x-amz-date", "20130524T000000Z")
        .header("x-amz-content-sha256", contentSha256)
        .buildS3(request, contentSha256)
        .getSignature();
```

If you want to implement it yourself take a look at https://github.com/lucasweb78/aws-v4-signer-java/blob/master/src/main/java/uk/co/lucasweb/aws/v4/signer/Signer.java for an example of how to do it.

Disclaimer: I'm the libraries author.